# php forward visitor ip to nginx

Tags: php, linux, nginx, ip, forward

i am trying to send real visitor ip to nginx from php

this is the situation

server A - exmaple.com/a.php

server B - example/file.txt

when access  exmaple.com/a.php it download file.txt located on server b

but nginx logs show server A ip as requested download, i guess that correct cause the file.txt downloaded via a.php located on server A

so how can i send the ip of the visitor instead of the server to nginx

i already have this in my nginx config

```
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

thank you

Comment: Please add your attempt so we can help you further.

Comment: added my php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add it to your request headers.

```
$opts['http']['header'] = 'X-Real-IP: ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\r\n";
```

You would also need to configure Nginx to accept this, with `set_real_ip_from` config directives.

A better option would be to use cURL (see @Terra's answer), which gives you a bit more flexibility than the fopen wrappers.

The **best** option however is just to let Nginx do this.  It's far more efficient than piping all this data through PHP.  Use `proxy_pass`.

Comment: i am bit confused here sorry,nginx $remote_addr is giving server A ip, how can i make it give me visitor ip address

Comment: nvm i figure it out, i was also behind cf so i had to add there ips also, thank for help

Comment: for some reason when i add this using video url the video is not seekable any idea ?         $opts['http']['header']="Range: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']."\r\nCookie: video_key=".$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'];
  $opts['http']['header'] = 'X-Real-IP: ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\r\n";

Comment: Not all videos are seekable.  In any case, don't do this in PHP... use Nginx.

Answer (score 2):

Server A: add `X-Real-IP` header with client's IP to outgoing request. This part depends on you code. For example, if CURL, you need to add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [ 'X-Real-IP: '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ])`.

Server B: you need to configure nginx. Add to nginx's `server` config block:
`set_real_ip_from SERVER_A_IP;`
`real_ip_header X-Real-IP;` (not required because default value)

Comment: thanks, can $ch be replaced with something else ? cause i can not add it to my perl file

Comment: @Lolak Perl?  Where are you using Perl?